# table xyz has no column named pqr in android sqlite

Tags: android

```
//  private static final String SQL_CREATE_XYZ= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + XYZ 
            + " (" +ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + ABC+ "TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
            + DEF+ "TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
            + GHI+ "TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
            + JKL+ "TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
            + MNO+ "TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            + STU+"TEXT DEFAULT NULL"
            + PQR+"TEXT DEFAULT NULL " + "); ";
```

this is my create table info.  while inserting data into database i am getting xyz has no column named pqr. what is the problem in this one.

Comment: If you added column `pqr` after running application once in device, please clear data, and rerun application and check. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25481641/1777090)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your statement.

Change

```
+ STU+"TEXT DEFAULT NULL"
```

to

```
+ STU+"TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
```

Comment: i added like above. but still same issue.